# ValueAnimator to a date (long value)

Tags: android, animation, animator

Now I can animate a date with a double value in seconds to create a Counter Effect. The problem is that I want to format it with DateUtils to a 00:00 format, then it is a long value.

How can I animate it?

Example of code with a double value:

```
ValueAnimator valueAnimator= new ValueAnimator();
valueAnimator.setObjectValues(0d, doubleValue);
valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
   public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
         textView.setText(String.valueOf(decimalFormat.format(animation.getAnimatedValue())));
   }
});
valueAnimator.setEvaluator(new TypeEvaluator<Double>() {
   public Double evaluate(float fraction, Double startValue, Double endValue) {
         return (startValue + (endValue - startValue) * fraction);
   }
});
valueAnimator.setDuration(1200);
valueAnimator.start();
```

Comment: `DateUtils` uses `long` in format related methods so simply use `ValueAnimator.ofInt`

Comment: i mean: no need for a custom `TypeEvaluator`

Comment: Really I get this code from StackOverflow, I don't know how it works exactly, can you post an answer with a detailed snippet so I can accept your comment?